pip install pycrypto error (subprocess-exited-with-error)
I was installing pycrypto to code AES 128 CBC algorithm.
But I got this error(with figure). What should i do?
C:\python\python_InternalLock>pip install pycrypto
Collecting pycrypto
  Downloading pycrypto-2.6.1.tar.gz (446 kB)
     ---------------------------------------- 446.2/446.2 kB 2.3 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: pycrypto
  Building wheel for pycrypto (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [2 lines of output]
      warning: GMP or MPIR library not found; Not building Crypto.PublicKey._fastmath.
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pycrypto
  Running setup.py clean for pycrypto
Failed to build pycrypto
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pycrypto, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Error of pycrypto
Searched about Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 and GMP or MPIR library. But I didn't get solution of this problem. Please let me know how to solve this problem.

https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pycrypto/info : Warning: PyCrypto seems not maintained anymore It seems that the PyCrypto project has not been maintained since 2014. The developers are not doing any activity on the official repository during these years and they are not providing support about issues. This is why it's suggested to replace it with the PyCryptodome.

PyCrypto 2.x is unmaintained, obsolete, and contains security vulnerabilities.
It is recommended that you use Cryptography for new applications or PyCryptodome for existing software that depends on PyCrypto.
See https://www.pycrypto.org/
